# Showing events on a multi room scheduler

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I write a web app that shows events on a multi room scheduler. I use VueJS for the first time on a real project.

Here, I loop through the events array every room column (two nested v-for). In jQuery I need to loop once through this array to fill all columns at once.

My question: is there any other more efficient way to write this code that fills rooms divs with events in Vue?

```js
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            rooms: [
               {id: 1, title: 'Room 1' },
               {id: 2, title: 'Room 2' }
            ],
            events: [
              { id: 1, start: 230, duration: 30, title: 'Event 1', room_id: 2},
              { id: 2, start: 400, duration: 45, title: 'Event 2', room_id: 1}
            ]
        }
    })
```

```css
.agenda-wrapper { max-width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll; }

  .agenda { padding-top: 50px; overflow: hidden; }
  
.room {
    width:300px;
    height:1170px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background:#ECECEC;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}

.room span {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.event {
    display: block;
    background:#fff;
    color:#4B6EA8;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-left:4px solid #c4183c;
    position:absolute;
    padding:0 10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 280px;
}
```

```html
<div class="agenda-wrapper" id="app">
  <div class="agenda" :style="{ width: (rooms.length * 350) + 'px' }">
    <div class="room" v-for="room in rooms" :key="room.id">
      <span>{{ room.title }}</span>
      <div class="event" 
        :style="{ top: event.start + 'px', height: event.duration + 'px'}" 
        v-for="event in events" 
        v-if="event.room_id === room.id">
      <h5>{{ event.title }}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Code Review! I'm planning on answering your question later, but just out of curiousity: How would you do it in jQuery?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! I think it would be something like that: '$.each(events, function(event){
            var el = $("<div></div>").addClass("event").css({ "height": event.duration + "px", "top": event.start + "px" }).text(event.title);
            $('.room').data('place', event.place_id).append(el);
        });'

Comment: I also think that maybe I need to do it on backend to make a rooms array look like that: { id: 1, title: 'Room 1', events: [{ id: 1, title: 'Event 1', start: 90, duration: 30 }] }

Comment: Yes, backend is Laravel app. It has two models: Room and Event. Event belongsTo Room.

Answer (score 3):

I asked you how you would do it in jQuery and you said that you would do something like:

> ```
> $.each(events, function(event){
>     var el = $("<div></div>")
>         .addClass("event")
>         .css({ "height": event.duration + "px", "top": event.start + "px" })
>         .text(event.title);
>     $('.room').data('place', event.place_id).append(el);
> });
> ```

And sure, this would only loop through the `events` array once. But what happens in every iteration? It does a jQuery search for `$('.room').data('place', event.place_id)`, which is not a constant-time lookup operation, so this approach might be slower than what you think it is.

---

Now, for your Vue approach. You said:

> maybe I need to do it on backend to make a rooms array look like that: `{ id: 1, title: 'Room 1', events: [{ id: 1, title: 'Event 1', start: 90, duration: 30 }] }`

And yes, I agree with this. Putting the `events` inside your rooms makes much more sense.

As for your Vue template, overall the code looks fine. I'm not a CSS expert so I don't know if there's something you can improve there, but there probably is. Maybe consider using [CSS Grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), where each room could be one column, and time-slots could be rows? The current approach of having 1px = 1 minute seems a bit unnatural to me.

As for this part:

```
<div class="room" v-for="room in rooms" :key="room.id">
  <span>{{ room.title }}</span>
  <div class="event" 
    :style="{ top: event.start + 'px', height: event.duration + 'px'}" 
    v-for="event in events" 
    v-if="event.room_id === room.id">
  <h5>{{ event.title }}</h5>
</div>
```

The only thing I would change is to put `v-for` and `v-if` before your `:style`-binding, as they are more important to be aware about, this is mostly my personal opinion though.

```
<div class="room" v-for="room in rooms" :key="room.id">
  <span>{{ room.title }}</span>
  <div class="event" 
    v-for="event in events" 
    v-if="event.room_id === room.id"
    :style="{ top: event.start + 'px', height: event.duration + 'px'}" 
    >
  <h5>{{ event.title }}</h5>
</div>
```

It would be nicer if your events would be inside the rooms, as then you could write:

```
<div class="room" v-for="room in rooms" :key="room.id">
  <span>{{ room.title }}</span>
  <div class="event" 
    v-for="event in room.events" 
    :style="{ top: event.start + 'px', height: event.duration + 'px'}" 
    >
  <h5>{{ event.title }}</h5>
</div>
```

I would recommend in the future to use a `Room` component and a `RoomEvent` component so that you could write:

```
<Room v-for="room in rooms" :key="room.id" />
```

And the room-component:

```
<div class="room">
  <span>{{ room.title }}</span>
  <RoomEvent v-for="event in room.events" />
</div>
```

I think that the `<h5>{{ event.title }}</h5>` belongs inside the `RoomEvent`

---

Overall a nice job!

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great review! I rewrote backend as I mentioned. Now the code is a bit faster. As for CSS, I will look at CSS Grids one more time, but I'm afraid it's more complicated and less supportive by old browsers way. Anyway, thanks for your advice!

Comment: Another small question: I have some plugins that need jQuery. Is it a good idea to use both jQuery (UI components like Select2) and Vue in same code?

Comment: @Alex Yes unfortunately CSS Grids are not supported by older browsers. Regarding jQuery: I have never used it together with Vue myself but I would recommend to try to get rid of jQuery. There is probably Vue alternatives that you can use instead, if you are looking for UI-components then I can recommend [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com) for example.